# Hide text or variable value in teamcity build log

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, teamcity, devops

Is there was way to hide a text in team city build log. I want to use a variable in the team city build logs ( the build will be running using bash shell script). The variable will be storing SSO token and later used in script at multiple places. so want to hide that SSO token. e.g.

`return_code= $(curl --$cert $request $url)`

when I run this line in my script with set-x on in my shell script it will return the sso token and it will be visible but I want to hide it while set -x is on. And then later I want to use return_code variable to run another curl something like this.

`curl --ssotoken=$retutn_code $endpoint`

In this line using $return_code makes sso token visible.

How can I hide sso token in the build logs.

Any option welcome.

Comment: Enable/disable `set [+-]x` maybe?

Comment: Hi @jitchisel  have to hide sso token while set -x is enabled

Comment: @Vicky: You can start your script with `set -x` at the top and place `set +x` just above the line: `return_code= $(curl --$cert $request $url)` and again `set -x` below this line...

Comment: @Vicky : Actually, the token should already become visible by the time you are doing the `return_code=$(curl --$cert $request $url)`. I would put the safety critical part of the script into a **separate** shell script (or a program of some other language) and make sure that inside **that** script, `-x`) is unset.